# CSS Overflow - Not working as expected

Tags: html, css, overflow

http://jsfiddle.net/bSnaG/

In my mind the above example should look like a grey box with `#x` not going past the edge and `#y` poking out the bottom.

But it's not like that - apparently setting `overflow-x: hidden;` causes `overflow-y: scroll | auto;`.

Is there any way around this?
I need to allow certain elements to escape the bounding box without setting `overflow: visible` on `#box`.

Comment: I can't come up with a solution using the markup you posted, but if you tell us more about what you need we might be able to suggest an alternative?

Comment: More detail is needed, what is the exact behavior/context of the items in the box and under which conditions do they get bound or hidden?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#y` can't break out of its bounding box without being taken out of the flow of the document.  Does adding `position: absolute;` to `#y` give the effect you're after?

**Update**

Restructured HTML example, including a containing box to allow everything to be easily positioned together.  Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/GfNbp

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="x"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="y"></div>
</div>


#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 10px;

    /* ADD THE OVERFLOW */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

#container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}

#x {
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #c1ffb2;
}

#y {
    width: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #c4b2ff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px; /* margin+padding */
    top: 30px; /* margin+padding+x-height */
}
```

Comment: As a proof of concept it works, but I still need `#y` to be relative to `#box`

Comment: Then add position: relative; to the #box

Comment: That won't work as it's not taking `#y` out of context. It has the same effect as not adding `position: absolute`. 

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: It sounds like the structure of your HTML is wrong then, and you don't actually want `#y` to be a child of `#box` as you don't want it to be bound by it in any way, just positioned next to it.  Take it outside of the box (ha ha) and it's a simple case of positioning.

Comment: It's kind of strange but just adding `position:absolute` to #y makes it work on Chrome 7. Since you said it needs to be relative to #box, does #box have any special positioning? As far as I tried, if you leave it on default, it works.

Comment: Thanks batwad for your help - you've given good answers and helpful comments so I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have, and it works:

```
#box {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 10px;

    /* ADD THE OVERFLOW */
    overflow-y:visible;
    overflow-x:hidden;

}

#x {
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #c1ffb2;
}


#y {
    width: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #c4b2ff;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you need to position #box absolutely either.

Comment: That will only work as long as the page itself doesn't scroll. Try adding `body { height: 1000px; }` to the example.

Comment: Have you tried using a different methodology?  Perhaps using a vertically-tiled graphic in an offset div layered above the #box div or something along those lines?

Comment: `position: fixed;` makes the block relative to viewport; not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your height: 100px in the outer div.  If you remove this height attribute, do you get the result you're looking for?

Otherwise, I think batwad's probably knocked the nail on the head using three divs.