# how to disable horizontal scrolling if overflow-x: hidden isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have this test document trying out sliding animations with the jquery waypoints plugin

http://teamdesigntree.com/test/

Whats going on is that a mobile user can scroll to the right because the divs are positioned all the way to the right before the animation happens. How can this be fixed? I applied overflow-x: hidden to the body as well as the main wrapper and it didnt seem to help.

Comment: try overflow:scroll; may be that helps.

Comment: Try this
  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995868/overflow-x-not-working-at-all),
 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153601/css-overflow-not-working-as-expected)

this will help you.

Comment: try this: 
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

Comment: i can't see any problem in this link.

Comment: I added  body { overflow-x:hidden; position:relative; } into the site, and it did not work.

Comment: Obviously, the term "a mobile user" is too generic. Could you mention which mobile devices (and browsers) have this issue?